# How do I pass values between variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have variables `Student1, Student2, Student3 and Student`

I assign values to Student1, Student2 and Student3 on the run.

Before Inserting these values in database, I assign those values to Student Variable and then insert them in database, something like:

```
For i = 1 to 3

InsertData = "Student" & i

Next
```

Here, I am not able to pass the Values for `Student1, Student2 and Student3 to Student` variable. How Can i do this?

Thanks in advance

CODE:

```
Student1 = "abc"
Student2 = "def"
Student3 = "ghi"

i = 0
For i = 1 To 3

    Set httpReq = New MSXML2.xmlhttp

    httpReq.Open "POST", InsertDataURL, False

    httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    InsertData = "Student" & i

    httpReq.send InsertData 
    InsertData = ""
    Set httpReq = Nothing
Next i
```

Comment: You're assigning a value to `InsertData`, but posting the string `PostData`

Comment: Thats a Typo, Updated it, still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to move the location of your vairable assignment to before you open the HTTP Request:

```
i = 0
For i = 1 To 3

    Set httpReq = New MSXML2.xmlhttp

    InsertData = "Student" & i

    httpReq.Open "POST", InsertData, False

    httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    httpReq.send PostData
    PostData = ""
    Set httpReq = Nothing
Next i
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where I assign value to a variable. InsertData variable still displays "Student1" as its value and not the actual vaule

Comment: ok, you made another edit.  If you want to do this in a loop you are going to need to add your variables to an array or collection or list or something that is enumerable.

Comment: could you give me an example?